# Cannot pass a parameter to a function using Angular directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to understand how directives and '$compile' work in angular, so I'm trying to bind an html button along with an onclick function to an angular variable.

More concretely, I just an alert to pop up when I click the button, that will display some text.

Here is my html (as simple as possible):

```
<div compile="test"></div>
```

Here is how I define the 'compile' directive:

```
angular.module("myApp").directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(
        function(scope) {
            return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
        },
        function(value) {
            element.html(value);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    )}
}]);
```

And here is the controller:

```
angular.module("myApp").controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.foo = function (input) {
        alert(input);
    };

    var str = "clicked";
    var result = "<button ng-click='foo(str)'>click me</button>";
    $scope.test = result;
}
```

The above code doesn't work, the alert displays 'undefined'. If, instead, I do the following, it works:

```
var result = "<button ng-click='foo(\"clicked\")'>click me</button>";
```

Any ideas what I am missing? What should I do to be able to pass a parameter to the function foo?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess in this case:

```
var result = "<button ng-click='foo(\"clicked\")'>click me</button>";
```

in alert you get "clicked", because you pass it like string argument.

```
 var result = "<button ng-click='foo(str)'>click me</button>";
```

- in this case str is not recognized as str variable.

try to use it in his way:

```
 var result = "<button ng-click='foo(\"" + str + "\")'>click me</button>".
```

Answer (score 1):

*ng-click* in your example is inserted into events loop stack, waiting for JS click event on its element. When it is fired, function under *ng-click* directive is executed with angular scope, your element belongs to, and there is no *str* variable assigned to the scope. When you use `var str = "clicked";`, *str* is a private variable within *myController*'s anonymous function. The easiest solution would be set *str* on scope:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  $scope.foo = function (input) {
    alert(input);
  };

  $scope.str = "clicked";
  var result = "<button ng-click='foo(str)'>click me</button>";
  $scope.test = result;
}]);
```

but keep in mind, that this scope variable may be modified until its execution.

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/HJCprBRmatl5ikRCJXWx?p=preview